# To access my android app old root folder from API 33

Tags: android, directory, permissions

My old Android App is used to have app folder in /XXX in full access mode, it contains many files either in txt or jpg.

I know api 33 can't do it like the old way, how can I migrate or access the data to continue working?

i have 2 ideas

- access the data by obtaining new file permission to /XXX (possible?)
- migrate /XXX to the default application folder (still possible in api 33 ?)

would you point me to some direction?

thank you

Comment: Use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE once to let the user choose that folder.

Comment: `app folder in /XXX ` Pretty unclear where this impossible path would be. Better tell full path.

Comment: @blackapps /XXX is just a root folder in the phone built-in memory

Comment: Impossible path.